# Input keyboard language issue in games

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

Its more of an annoyance than a problem as I've learn to live with it but still very annoying and if I can find an answer that would be great.

I got windows 10 and some games detects my french keyboard layout configured in the system. I've got the english language installed but my keyboard layout contains 2 of them. One for english and the other one for french since I write to french people.

To make it clear, in the language in windows 10, I got 1 english language installed. In that language, i got 2 layouts which is 1 for english and the other for french so I just press Shift + CTRL and it switches back and forth. No problem in windows application.

but the problem starts in games. If I have the french layout in my language, then the game detects it and will use it. So when I go in the binding, remap or keyboard key configuration I see those keys in french. For example, I will see `espace` instead of space. or `entree` (ya, its not even unicode so games cant use accents) instead of enter.

I could remove the french layout and this would fix it since I would only have the english layout and the game bind or maps would be in english but doing that everytime is unthinkable. Does someone have any answer or help on this issue ?